# ESP8266-01 How to connect the GPIO to Ground with a resistor as shown below in the image

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

[Connections I want on esp8266-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXpvo.png)

When I connect the gpio as shown in above image..
then the ESP goes in the programming mode and doesn't normally boot
please show me how to do so

Comment: If I understand correctly, the pin you've chosen to use puts the esp8266-01 module in bootloader mode. Maybe you should use another pin? Or maybe if you've run out of pins, you could choose a different module?

Comment: You could use a pullup ( Either external resistor or 
`pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);`  and invert the programming logic

Comment: How do I achieve that could you please elaborate? I desperately need the answer @datafiddler

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot , The key solution to this problem is to program the RX or the TX pins to work as GPIO and this very well solved my problem